# Delete global variable from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

**Code**

```
role = 'admin'

def f():
    del role

if role == 'admin':
    f()
else:
    pass
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hari\PycharmProjects\Card_Prj\ch.py", line 6, in <module>
    f()
  File "C:\Users\Hari\PycharmProjects\Card_Prj\ch.py", line 3, in f
    del role
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'role' referenced before assignment
```

If a role called admin exists then it should delete the variable role otherwise it should do nothing, that is what the code is doing.

I have tried different ways of executing this code but failed to do so.

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @ Krishna Chaurasia If a role called admin exists then it should delete the variable role otherwise it should do nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: add `global role` to `f()` or pass an arguement to the function

Comment: you can use `global role` to make it accessible in the function

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you refer to some Docs to understand how Global and Local Variable work but if you want to make it work, here is the required code:

```
role = 'admin'

def f():
    global role
    del role

if role == 'admin':
    f()
else:
    pass
```